Angular SSR fails to access .NET backend with SSL while client-side works fine
I'm encountering an SSL certificate issue with Angular SSR (Server-Side Rendering) when trying to access my .NET backend. The interesting part is that everything works perfectly fine on client-side rendering.
Environment

Angular 18 (also tested with Angular 19 RC)
.NET backend running on https://localhost:7205
Certificate is added to root certificate store and shows as trusted in browser

What's Working

Client-side requests work perfectly fine
Certificate is recognized as trusted in browser
Backend endpoints are accessible directly through browser

What's Not Working
During SSR, I get the following error when trying to make HTTP requests:
HTTP Error Intercepted: HttpErrorResponse {
      status: 0,
      statusText: 'Unknown Error',
      url: 'https://localhost:7205/api/Account/MyInfo',
      ok: false,
      message: 'Http failure response for https://localhost:7205/api/Account/MyInfo: 0 Unknown Error'
    }

I attempted to disable SSL verification on the server by adding this to server.ts:
Beside that, the file is the default.
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = '0';

However, this didn't resolve the issue.
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

setting env that way is not a working way.  you should set it as env variable before starting the process

@Andrei This is my hole npm start script
"cross-env NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 ng serve -c development --ssl --ssl-cert ./ssl/server.crt --ssl-key ./ssl/server.key"
Sadly still the same error

are you sure that the issue is ssl then?
